# Is there an order within a CSS file? Why is it being underlined (a href)

Tags: css

I have this CSS code:

```
    .mini-profile {
        padding: 12px;
        color: #333333;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    .mini-profile a {
        color: #333333;
    }

    .mini-profile a:hover {
        color:#08C;
    }

    .metadata{
        color: #999;
        text-decoration:none;

    }

    .metadata:hover{
        color: #999;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .metadata a{
        color: #999;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .metadata a:hover {
        color: #333333;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Now I have this:

```
    <div class="bs-docs-sidebar bs-docs-sidenav rounded-div-white mini-profile">
        <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="content">
            <div style="margin-left:50px;"><b style="display:block;">Antoine</b>
                <small class="metadata">View my profile page</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PspXV/

Now, why is the "View Profile" being underlined when it is being hovered? Why?! Is their an order in the file that I have to follow?

Comment: You have a mismatch between this code and the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.mini-profile a:hover {
    color:#08C;
    text-decoration:underline;
```

- this is why

and your div class is `class="bs-docs-sidebar bs-docs-sidenav rounded-div-white mini-profile"`

specifically `mini-profile`

Answer (score 2):

You defined this rule in your fiddle, but not in the CSS you provided for your question:

```
.mini-profile a:hover {
    ...
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Change `text-decoration: underline;` to `text-decoration: none;` to remove the underline appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Your metadata isn't inside an a tag but you're calling the hover on an a tag.

```
   <small class="metadata"><a href="#">View my profile page</a></small>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/PspXV/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
            <a href="www.google.com">
                <div class="content">
                    <div style="margin-left:50px;"><b style="display:block;">Antoine</b>
                    <small class="metadata">View my profile page</small></div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

This is a major violation of web standards. This will send the browser into quirks mode and could cause rendering issues. You should never put a block level element inside an inline element  ('div' inside 'a').